# Как найти есть ли подстрока "bar" в файле, начинающегося с foo?

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, файлы

Помогите составить правильное регулярное выражение. Нужно найти есть ли bar во всех файлах, в которых в начале файла есть строка foo. Имена файлов могут быть любые.

```
grep  -i "bar" "^foo"
```

Найдет bar во всех файлах с именами `foo*`, а как можно искать в файлах с содержимым? И можно ли как-то заставить вернуть не строку, а true или false?

```
foo some bar text bar
```

Должно вернуть true

Попробовал такую конструкцию

`grep ^foo *.txt  && grep bar *`

Но она выводит Все имена файлов с текстом foo, а потом с bar

Comment: А можно ли подобное в принципе сделать на grep - `найти есть ли bar во всех файлах, в которых в начале файла есть строка`?

Comment: @splash58 Я не знаю. Поэтому и ипрашиваю. Попробовал воспользоваться && и объединить две команды grep. но тоже не вышло. Сейчас дополню вопрос.

Comment: head - n1 вернет первую строку, можно из первых строк выбрать grep -v ^foo. А вот как дальше устроить водопровод, не подскажу - я им не пользуюсь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [стыкованием команд](https://docs.altlinux.org/ru-RU/archive/2.4/html-single/master/alt-docs-extras-linuxcovice/ch02s07.html) и выполнить такую:

```
 grep ^foo *.txt | grep bar *
```

То есть находим все txt файлы у которых в начале есть foo, перенаправляем вывод первой команды во вторую где находим bar.

Выводит имена нужных файлов : bar. Как превратить в true или false буду искать.

Comment: Это находит `foo` не только первой строкой, а в начале любой из строк (т.е. если вторая строка файла есть `foo123`, то этот файл тоже найдёт). Чтобы рекурсивно в текущей директории найти вхождения `bar` в файлы, у которых первая строка `foo`, можно использовать `grep 'bar' $(grep -m1 ^ -r . | grep -Po '.*(?=:foo)')`. Для `.txt` нерекурсивно в текущей директории замените `-r .` на `*.txt`.